# get name from another table while using sub query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a query like this:

```
select 
    F_ExhibitionCode,
    F_ExhibitorCode 
from 
    T_ExhibitorLocation 
where 
    F_ExhibitorCode in (
        select 
            F_Exhibitor_Code 
        from 
            T_Exhibitor 
        where 
            F_Exhibitor_Name  LIKE '%''%')
```

i have two more tables , one is  `*`T_Exhibition`*` and another one is "T_Exhibitor, `F_exhibiton` name is coming form  `T_Exhibition`
and `F_ExhibitorCode` is coming from the `T_Exhibitor` ,
final result i need like this: 
F_Exhibitonnaem, F_Exhibition code,F_exibitorname,F exhibitor code.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: in above query i want to add two column for getting ther value..how i can do this?

Comment: Sorry but I stil don't understand your question, can you edit your question explaining what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Seems like you need a join and not a sub query. Can you edit your question to include the relevant tables ddl statements?

Comment: Try to find something about JOIN syntax it shouldn't be that hard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand your tables structure, I would suggest something along these lines:

```
SELECT EL.F_ExhibitionCode, EL.F_ExhibitorCode, E.F_exhibiton_name
FROM T_ExhibitorLocation EL
INNER JOIN T_Exhibitor E ON(EL.F_ExhibitorCode = E.F_ExhibitorCode)
WHERE E.F_Exhibitor_Name LIKE '%''%'
```

Comment: i want to get exhibitor name also in this query